# I can set a multiple options on one variable in sass and use it?

Tags: css, sass, node-sass

Let me explain myself, i wanna do something like this in my code

```
$varible:{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 14px;
 height: 14px;
}
.circle{
   &:nth-child(1){
      &::after{
        $varible;
        position:absolute;
        ...
      }
   }
}
```

Create a variable that contains a lot of attributes, and then use it as a global setting later, does anybody know if this is possible, or how I can perform an action like this?

Comment: What about a [mixin](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin)?

Comment: the problem is, i dont know how to use mixin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mixin** is basically used to call a block of style but does not return any value unlike function in sass.

The `@mixin` directive lets you create CSS code that is to be reused throughout the website.
The `@include` directive is created to let you use (include) the mixin.

```
@mixin variable{
   display: inline-block; 
 width: 14px; 
 height: 14px;
 }

 .circle{    
&:nth-child(1){
      &::after{
        @include: variable;
        position:absolute;
        ...
      } 
   }}
```

Comment: Thx a lot for the explain, i can resolve my problem with this